# Check if array contains object with property equal to a specific value

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I have a helm `values.yaml` file that contains the following:

```
env:
  - name: VAR_1
    value: VALUE_1
  - name: VAR_2
    value: VALUE_2
```

In my helm chart I'd like to have an `if` that checks if `.Values.env` contains an item with `name=VAR_1`.

I tried with `{{ if has "VAR_1" .Values.env }}` but I am not sure how to do object comparison, or to interpolate `.Values.env` to `.Values.env[].name` (similar to `jq`).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Looping with the range action](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures.md#looping-with-the-range-action) and [If/Else](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/control_structures.md#ifelse).

Also you can remove duplicates with [uniq function](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html), however same `name` with different `value` will be considered unique.

```
{{- range .Values.env | uniq -}}
  {{- if eq .name "VAR_1" -}}
    {{ .name }}: {{ .value }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end}}
```

**Update:**

Here's a *hacky* **_helpers.tpl** function that will output only the first occurrence of element with "VAR_1" name

```
{{- define "chart.getUniqueValue" -}}

  {{- $myDict := dict }}
  {{- $searchKey := "VAR_1" }}

  {{- range .Values.env  | reverse}}
    {{- $_ := set $myDict .name .value }}
  {{- end }}

  {{- range $k, $v := $myDict }}
    {{- if eq $searchKey $k}}
      {{- $k }} : {{ $v }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}

{{- end -}}
```

Comment: That's what I did, but in fact, what I need is to do something **once** in case the value I am looking for is present. Now, theoretically if someone adds 2 values, then I am going to add my thing twice. Is there something like `break` ?

Comment: I am not sure if `uniq` would work if you have `name: VAR_1 ; value: VALUE_1 ; name: VAR_1 ; value: VALUE_2`

Comment: Anyway, the question was more of *"Is there a way not to make this hacky"*, but in the end, there might not be.

Comment: I've added a _hacky_ solution as well